# hover handle on nest element using jquery

Tags: jquery, mouseenter

I am struggling to apply hover on very inner elements. I have been working on this issue for a very long time but still, have no clues on how to solve this problem. The code below is something I have done so far.

I want to have an alert message when my mouse is hovering on/off the "a" tag (link2/link3.....). Unfortunately, my attempt did not work out.

```js
(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#links').hover(function() {
              alert("mouse is 
                pointing ")},function(){ alert("
                mouse is not pointing ")})
              })
          })()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div id="links">
    <h1><a>link1</a></h1>
    <div><h2><a> link2</a></h2></div>
    <div><h2><a> link3</a></h2></div>
    <div><h2><a> link4</a></h2></div>
    <div><h2><a> link5</a></h2></div>
    <div><h2><a> link6</a></h2></div>
    <div><h2><a> link7</a></h2></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What do you mean by not working? At the moment you're listening for hover on the outer `#links` container, not the inner links themselves. Is that what you want? You would also do well to use semicolons to terminate statements.

Answer (score 1):

Both your html and javascript structure was broken. Fixed it in below snippet.

Made the following changes to fix your code:

- In your html i changed `</body>` to `</div>`
- In your javascript added `;` and fixed the structure.
- Added the `a` element in your element selector to select all `a` elements within `#links`

Made the following changes for code improvement:

- Changed `alert()` to `console.log()` for smoother debugging.
- Changed the deprecated `$(document).ready(function(){})` to the recommended `$(function(){})`

```js
(function() {
  $(function(){
    $('#links a').hover(
      function() {
        console.log("mouse is pointing ");
      },function(){ 
        console.log("mouse is not pointing ");
      }
    );
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div id="links">
    <h1><a>link1</a></h1>
    <div>
      <h2><a> link2</a></h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2><a> link3</a></h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2><a> link4</a></h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2><a> link5</a></h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2><a> link6</a></h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2><a> link7</a></h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mark up selection is wrong. Use find `a` inside div  like below.

```js
(function() {
  $('#links').find('a').hover(
    function() {
      console.log("mouse is pointing ");
    },
    function() {
      console.log("mouse is not pointing ");
    }
  );
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div id="links">
    <h1><a>link1</a></h1>
    <div>
      <h2><a> link2</a></h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2><a> link3</a></h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2><a> link4</a></h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2><a> link5</a></h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2><a> link6</a></h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2><a> link7</a></h2>
    </div>
  </div>
```